# I have a text file. I generate a voice-over wav file using TTS. How can I generate subtitle for it?

Tags: python, difflib, openai-whisper

I have a text file. I generate a voice-over wav file using TTS. How can I generate subtitles for it?
I use Azure and/or Coqui-AI TTS depending on the case.

I currently generate subtitles using the offline openai-Whisper model. But, it doesn't recognize words correctly. How can I compare and fix them?
Or do you have any alternative solutions for it?

Since I have the original text file, it should be easy to compare and correct the misrecognized words, but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the original text file?

Comment: How can I get time stamps for them? Or how can I compare and correct the misrecognized words?

Comment: You can use Whisper by OpenAI, or AssemblyAI https://www.assemblyai.com/products/core-transcription

Comment: actually, i have mentioned that. It doesnt recognize all words correctly. I need the correct that words.